# comparing results

Tags: statistics

let's say I have two datasets, A and B, which contain points. Now, I obtain three datasets from each of those datasets by applying some random point removal method. Now, I have 8 datasets in total. Then I run some calculation algorithm on all of them on two different machines X and Y, and obtain the following results on how long for each of them the elapsed time was.

```
 datasets  |   A  |  A-1  |  A-2 |  A-3   |  B   |  B-1  | B-2  | B-3
 time
 X         |  a1  |  b1   |  c1  |   d1   |  e1  |   f1  |  g1  |  h1
 Y         |  a2  |  b2   |  c2  |   d2   |  e2  |   f2  |  g2  |  h2
```

Now, how can i tell which machine performed better? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to do? provide some background...

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but wouldn't you just subtract the times, and call the machine that performed the test in the shortest time the "best performer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it depends on how you want to take the change in the dataset size into account (assuming that the datasets that have had points removed are smaller and have not been zero-padded or anything like that).

If you first assume that the algorithm is `O(n)` i.e. that the complexity increases linearly with the number of items, then you could normalise the times by the number of items. So the normalised times for `A` would be `a1/size(A)` and `a2/size(A)` and so on.

This however does assume quite a lot, the main assumption being that your assessment of performance would be a comparison of run times between machines.